# What's wrong with my code that user input won't go in django database?

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite, jinja2

All I want is for user input to go into the database upon user clicking on `Submit` but instead I get an error in my browser that says:

```
RuntimeError at /content
You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and 
you have APPEND_SLASH set. 
Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. 
Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/content/ (note the trailing 
slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
```

I know I'm very close to making this happen, I just want to know what I'm missing or where I messed up.

Here's `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Email
from django.core.exceptions import *

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'personal/home.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'personal/basic.html',{'content':['If you would like more information, leave your email.']})

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_id = request.POST.get(name = search_id)
        try:
            user = Email.objects.get(name=search_id)
            # do something with user
            html = ("<H1>%s</H1>", user)
            return HttpResponse(html)
        except Email.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse("no such user")
        else:
            return render(request, 'basic.html')
```

Here's `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^content/', views.contact, name='content'),
]
```

Here's `basic.html`:

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
<style type="text/css">
    h1 {
        color: #2e6da4;
        font-family: Chalkboard;
    }

    .text {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

    {% for c in content %}
        <h1>{{c}}</h1>
    {% endfor %}

    <div class="form-group">
        <form method="POST" action="/content">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="textfield">

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If any of the below answers helped you to resolve your issue, please mark it as accepted. It's a good practice in StackOverflow :)

Comment: If any of the below answers helped you to resolve your issue, please mark it as accepted. It's a good practice in StackOverflow :)

Comment: @nik_m I will try them out whenever I get the chance, then I'll accept it if it works :).  Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're `POST`ing the data at the url `/content` instead of `/content/`. Either, change to `<form method="POST" action="/content/">` or better change to `<form method="POST" action="{% url 'content' %}">` using the [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag.

Answer (score 0):

Django has a feature that can automatically redirect URLs such as */content* to */content/*. But, this feature doesn't work when you are using the POST HTTP method. Django is trying to tell you that it tried to do this redirect, but it couldn't because you were using a POST.

To correct this, the action in your form markup must match the url in your urls.py.

So you can try changing your HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/content">
```

to

```
<form method="POST" action="/content/">
```

Or, you can change your urls:

```
url(r'^content/', views.contact, name='content'),
```

by removing the slash, and adding an end of line regex:

```
url(r'^content$', views.contact, name='content'),
```

Either will work, so long as they match.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, your desired behavior goes like this:

1. a user visits /content in their browser
2. your Django server responds by rendering `basic.html`
3. the user enters their email into the form and submits
4. the form posts to /content with some data
5. the server creates an `Email` object with the given email and stores it in the database

As for the error, take a look at this info from the Django docs:

> APPEND_SLASH
>
> Default: True
>
> When set to True, if the request URL does not match any of the patterns in the URLconf and it doesn’t end in a slash, an HTTP redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended. Note that the redirect may cause any data submitted in a POST request to be lost.

It is telling you to add a `/` to the end of the forms action, like this `action="/content/"` because in your `urls.py` you specified `url(r'^content/'...`

Or, if you don't want to worry about all this "trailing slash" business, go into your `settings.py` and add

```
APPEND_SLASH = False
```

However, there is more to do. Currently, your `def contact` function only handles GET requests and is clueless about what to do when you POST some form data. Let's fix this:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'personal/basic.html', {'content': ['If you would like more information, leave your email.']})
    
    elif request.method == "POST":  
        email = Email(name=request.POST.get("textfield"))
        email.save()
        return render(request, 'basic.html')
```